# Assign individual tuple items to multiple dataframe columns using df.apply() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns `A` and `B` and a user-defined function that performns two calculations based on the values in `A` and returns a tuple with two items, `output1` and `output2`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[5,4,3,2,1]})

def myfunc(row):

    selected_row = row['A']

    output1 = selected_row + 10
    output2 = selected_row + 20

    return (output1, output2)
```

What I'd like to do is assign the values of `output1` and `output2` to two separate dataframe columns, `C` and `D`. I'm so far able to assign the entire returned tuple (with both items) to a signle column as such:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(myfunc,axis=1)
```

I'd like to be able to do this for two different columns, with `output1` going to column `C` and `output2` going to column `D`; I'm visualizing something like this:

```
df['C'], df['D'] = df.apply(myfunc,axis=1)
```

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: You might as well just loop over with `iterrows`...

Answer (score 0):

Does `myfunc` do anything that actually requires both columns?  In your example it doesn't, so you actually don't need to use apply (and probably don't want to, because it's slow).

You could use `df.assign` instead:

`df.assign(C=lambda x: x.A + 10, D=lambda x: x.B + 20)`

Comment: It doesn't require both columns -- just a specific column from a dataframe -- but it does contain multiple steps (the calculation here was used as a simpler example for brevity).

Comment: Great.  The value of each keyword arg just needs to be a callable, so you can define a func to take a dataframe and then call it like: `df.assign(C=my_func)`.  Just remember to work column-wise rather than row-wise, as that will be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of returning a tuple, I added an argument to select which output to return, `output1` or `output2`. I now get the desired result using two lines for `df.apply`, one for each new column, since `df.appy` appears to take keyword or positional arguments when "applying" a function, e.g. `df.apply(myfunc,output='output1',axis=1)`. Is there a way to similarly assign functions with additional arguments using `df.apply`?